# How to add slide animation for an image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, lightbox, image-gallery

I am trying to make a responsive image gallery in vanilla JS, I have a function and I am passing the image source as its parameter, and every time I am only changing the source on the click of next or previous button. Here is the function:

```
   this.open = function (src) {

    if (!src) {
        return false;
    }

    for (count = 0; count <= imgSrc.length; count++) {
        if (imgSrc[count] == src)
            break;
        var tempSrc = imgSrc[count];
    }

    imgRatio = false; // clear old image ratio for proper resize-values

    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.setAttribute('src', src);

    // hide overflow by default / if set

    if (!this.opt || !isset(this.opt.hideOverflow) || this.opt.hideOverflow) {
        body.setAttribute('style', 'overflow: hidden');
    }

    this.box.setAttribute('style', 'padding-top: 0');

    this.wrapper.innerHTML = '';

    this.wrapper.appendChild(img);

    // console.log(this.wrapper.innerHTML);

    addClass(this.box, 'jslghtbx-active');

    // already show wrapper due to bug where dimensions are not
    // correct in IE8

    if (isIE8) {
        addClass(that.wrapper, 'jslghtbx-active');
    }

    imgText.innerHTML = Details.static_data.gallery[count][3];

    var checkClassInt = setInterval(function () {
        if (hasClass(that.box, 'jslghtbx-active') && img.complete) {

            // wait few ms to get correct image-dimensions
            setTimeout(function () {

                that.resize();

                // add active-class for all other browsers

                setTimeout(function () {
                    addClass(that.wrapper, 'jslghtbx-active');
                }, 10);
                clearInterval(checkClassInt);
            }, 40);
        }
    }, 10); };
```

Is there any way so that I can attach animate kind of attribute to the image to have a sliding kind of animation. Please suggest your valuable feedback. [ NOTE: I am using this script https://github.com/felixhagspiel/jsOnlyLightbox ]

Comment: Please put your code in JS Fiddle so people can help you.

Comment: You could use CSS to animate left/right and then just change the position of image when the button is clicked. This lacks support in older IE (I think it's supported in IE > 10). For older browsers, you could look at this example: [Vanilla JS animate](http://codepen.io/tylerama/pen/veCxy).

Comment: Here, I am only changing the src of the image , and inside the div there is only one image, it would be helpful if you can tell me how to achieve it..